# SSH connection timed out while connecting to ec2 after apache2 installation

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I created an ec2 instance in AWS with ubuntu AMI and done all necesaary things to connect to the domain by setting up elsatic IP, Security Group, Route 53. Then I got the PEM file and connected to the SSH using private keys.

It is all working fine till I installed apache2 and restarted the apache server.

Then after, it is showing connection timed out to port 22 (SSH)

[image: SSH Connection error]

here is the security group inbound rules

[image: Security group inbound rules]

then checked in instance log got this thing at the bottom

```
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started The Apache HTTP Server.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Dispatcher daemon for systemd-networkd.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Snappy daemon.
         Starting Wait until snapd is fully seeded...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Wait until snapd is fully seeded.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Multi-User System.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Graphical Interface.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
         Starting Apply the settings specified in cloud-config...
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.
[   13.456104] cloud-init[1033]: Cloud-init v. 18.3-9-g2e62cb8a-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 running 'modules:config' at Wed, 06 Feb 2019 12:07:07 +0000. Up 13.29 seconds.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Apply the settings specified in cloud-config.
         Starting Execute cloud user/final scripts...
[   14.093385] cloud-init[1060]: Cloud-init v. 18.3-9-g2e62cb8a-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 running 'modules:final' at Wed, 06 Feb 2019 12:07:08 +0000. Up 13.95 seconds.
[   14.108125] cloud-init[1060]: Cloud-init v. 18.3-9-g2e62cb8a-0ubuntu1~18.04.2 finished at Wed, 06 Feb 2019 12:07:08 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2Local.  Up 14.08 seconds
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Started Execute cloud user/final scripts.
[[0;32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Cloud-init target.
```

**EDIT:**

AMI has some issues, created new instance and configured all again now it is working fine.

Comment: reboot your instance and try again.

Answer (score 0):

May be you have enable firewall during Apache installation and allow only few ports in firewall.

I follow this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3hLmDS179YE) and was able to connect with instance through session manager.
Steps to connect with instance though session manager when ssh not works

**A. Create Role and assign policy**

**1. Choose entity type AWS and use case ec2**

[image]

**2. Attach policy**

[image]

**3. tags skip**

**4. Review: Add role name**
[image]

---

**B. Attach above role with instance and save.**
[image]
**c. Reboot your instance and try to connect with session manager**
[image]

After login just disable firewall `sudo ufw disable` and check all inbound rule defined in security group should work